# R: Using "Gsub" a lost my data frame format

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have this Data Frame:

```
  Campaña           Visitas  Compras
1 faceBOOKAds-1     524       2
2 FacebookAds-2      487      24
3 fcebookAds-3      258       4
4 Email1            8         7
```

And i want this:

```
  Campaña    Visitas  Compras
1 FBAds1     524       2
2 FBAds2     487      24
3 FBAds3     258       4
4 Email1       8       7
```

1) I've read that "GSUB" would do the work so i've used this:

```
DataGoogle2 <- gsub("faceBOOKAds-1", "FBAds", DataGoogle1$Campaña)
```

But i get this vector object (As you see i've lost my data.frame format):

```
[1] "FBAds"              "FacebookAds-2"      "fcebookAds-3"      "Email1" ...
```

2) Then i try to use: as.data.frame:

```
DataGoogle2 <- as.data.frame(gsub("faceBOOKAds-1", "FBAds", DataGoogle1$Campaña))
```

But get this (No data frame format):

```
1                                                FBAds
2                                        fFacebookAds-2
3                                        fcebookAds-3
4                                               Email1
```

How can i get what i need? I know that the replacement method is not so good. What i need the most is not to loose the Data Frame format, but any help with the REGEX part is welcome!

Comment: BTW, did you post this question (or one very similar to it) on R-Help also?  My understanding is that it is not a good practice to cross-post or multi-post or whatever the term might be for asking the same or similar questions on two sites simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you used the following code:

```
DataGoogle2 <- gsub("faceBOOKAds-1", "FBAds", DataGoogle1$Campaña)
```

R reads that you want to your data frame to consist of DataGoogle1$Campaña column only and hence you get that output.

In stead, try this:

```
DataGoogle2$Campaña <- gsub("faceBOOKAds-1", "FBAds", DataGoogle1$Campaña)
```

This way you are saying that you want the COLUMN and not the DATA FRAME to be transformed. In any code, your LHS of expression is as important as your RHS code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @user3694373! It is more clear now, what i was trying was wrong. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use transform (and another regex).

```
DataGoogle2 <- transform(DataGoogle1, Campaña = sub("(?i)fa?cebook(.*)-(.*)", 
                                                    "FB\\1\\2", Campaña))
#   Campaña Visitas Compras
# 1  FBAds1     524       2
# 2  FBAds2     487      24
# 3  FBAds3     258       4
# 4  Email1       8       7
```

The functions `sub` and `gsub` return a vector. Hence, the information of all other columns is  not present in the output. With `transform` you can modify columns of an existing data frame and return a new one.

In the regex, `(?i)` starts the *non*-case sensitive mode. Furthermore, I used `sub` since I assume that there is never more than one match per string.

Comment: Thanks Steve. May you explain this points= 1) Why sub instead of gsub. It is because the ocurrences in this Data Frame are likely to just one (per line/entry)?

2) In the regex: (?i) means capital "F" is optional?

How would i apply it to mean: no matter if any of the letters is capital or not, just match this regex. Thanks so much.

Comment: @OmarGonzales I added some explanations.

Comment: Thanks, Sven. I would appriciate a good book in Regular Expresions for R. I'm reading "Master Regular Expresions 3Edition", and it talks about Regular Expresions based on the Perl engine. But any recomendations are welcome. 

*Just to get everything clear: what do the \\1\\2 in the regex? I think it matches the same "Ads" part, but don't get the logic.

Comment: @OmarGonzales, you might wanna look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html) under "Replacing ..." for further explanations. Btw, beeing able to use `(?i)` instead of `ignore.case = TRUE` was new to me.

Comment: A very good explanation of regex and string processing was done by Gaston Sanchez.  It is a free PDF of about 100 pages with the title "Handling and Processing Strings in R."  He does not address capturing groups and lookaround assertions, but he is very good on the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do direct replacement on the first column. This replaces the desired parts in the first column only by operating on the first column only. And this will keep the desired data frame structure.

```
> dat[[1]] <- gsub("f(.*)[-]", "FBAds", dat[[1]], ignore.case = TRUE)
> dat
#   Campaña Visitas Compras
# 1  FBAds1     524       2
# 2  FBAds2     487      24
# 3  FBAds3     258       4
# 4  Email1       8       7
```

...presuming your *original* data is called `dat`.